# Count (Select * Join) mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I'm stuck on this for hours, I'm trying to `COUNT` how many subscribers are there in Group A, Group B, Group C for this particular query:

```
SELECT rh.id_subscriber, rh.bill_month, rh.bill_year,
 ( 
     SELECT tbl_gen_info.gen_data_03 
     FROM tbl_subscriber 
     LEFT JOIN tbl_gen_info ON tbl_subscriber.bill_area_code = tbl_gen_info.gen_data_01
     WHERE rh.id_subscriber = tbl_subscriber.id_subscriber

 ) AS group_area

FROM tbl_reading_head AS rh
WHERE rh.id_soa_head IS NULL 
AND rh.read_status <> 'Beginning' 
AND rh.rec_status = 'active'
ORDER BY rh.id_subscriber
```

The sub-query gets the Group area `gen_data_03` from `tbl_gen_info`

Tables contain this information:

```
tbl_gen_info
--------------------------------------------
| gen_category | gen_data_01 | gen_data_03 |
--------------------------------------------
| Area Code    | Camacho St. | Group A     |
--------------------------------------------

tbl_subscriber
----------------------------------
| id_subscriber | bill_area_code | 
----------------------------------
|        1      | Camacho St.    | 
----------------------------------

tbl_reading_head
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| id_subscriber | id_soa_head | read_status | bill_month | bill_year |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|        1      |     NULL    |   Metered   |     10     |   2017    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[image: Query Result]

Notice that each id_subscriber has two (2) rows (one for electric, one for water). After grouping by id_subscriber:

```
GROUP BY rh.id_subscriber
```

I got this:

[image: Result]

I tried adding `COUNT` before the sub-query making it:

```
  COUNT(SELECT tbl_gen_info.gen_data_03 ...) AS group_area
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: I'm having a hard time following your question.  Please _edit_ your question and show us sample data for the three tables involved along with the output you actually expect.  I'm pretty sure you can get rid of that nasty subquery in the select list, but we won't know for sure unless you show us some data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT rh.group_area, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT rh.id_subscriber, rh.bill_month, rh.bill_year,
             (SELECT tbl_gen_info.gen_data_03 
              FROM tbl_subscriber LEFT JOIN
                   tbl_gen_info
                   ON tbl_subscriber.bill_area_code = tbl_gen_info.gen_data_01
             WHERE rh.id_subscriber = tbl_subscriber.id_subscriber
            ) as group_area
      FROM tbl_reading_head rh
      WHERE rh.id_soa_head IS NULL AND
            rh.read_status <> 'Beginning' AND
            rh.rec_status = 'active'
     ) rh
GROUP BY rh.group_area;
```

Comment: Wonderful! after some adjustment to your query i was able to get the results I wanted. Thank you so much!